# Zend Session Error, Session must be started before any output has been sent to browser

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

Changed my server for zend framework web application configured database connection and also written some basic .htaccess file for the website but after that error is coming when trying to run index.php file in which error is generating from Zend_Session::start(); line present in the index.php
[image]

Please good and kind developers out there please help me solve this error thanks a lot in advance.
If you want some of the code of my zend web app. I can share these things over this query.

I tried ob_start() in the beginning of the index.php but it will also lead to some other errors but not providing me the perfect solution.